# What are all the elements of $\mathbb Z_{2}[x] / <x^3+x+1>$

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic

List all the elements of $\frac{\mathbb Z_{2}[x]}{<x^3+x+1>}$ (the set of remainders)

Please verify my understanding:

- Since the polynomial is of degree 3, the remainders must have degree at most 2.
- We are working in $\mathbb Z_{2}[x]$ so the coefficients must be 0 or 1

Is it $\{0, 1, x, x^2, x+1, x^2+1\}$ ?

Comment: Hint $\rm\ \ x^2 + S \not\subset S\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque can you elaborate? $x^2 + S$ is not a subset of $S$?

Comment: Now that you know what the seven nonzero elements of your field are, you should improve your understanding of its structure by writing down the powers of (for instance) $x$ in order, and noticing that you now have a logarithm table for the multiplicative structure of the field. I always do this when I'm working with a field that has more than $4$ elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $ $ Polynomials in $\Bbb Z_2[x]$ of degree $\le 2$ have form $\rm\ \Bbb c_0\! + c_1 x +\, c_2 x^2\:$ for $\rm\:c_i \in \Bbb Z_2,\:$ so there are $\rm\: 2\cdot 2\cdot 2 = 8\:$ in total, not 6. Indeed, your proposed coset rep's are not closed under addition, so they cannot comprise a *complete* set of cosets rep's for the quotient ring.

Answer (score 2):

$\{0, 1, x, x^2, x+1, x^2+1,x^2+x,x^2+x+1\}+<x^3+x+1>$

Comment: ah of course, missing $x^2+x$ and $x^2+x+1$! thanks

Answer (score 1):

The elements in $\mathbb Z[x]/<x^3+x+1>$ are equivalence classes *represented* by polynomials of degree less than $3$. So, formally speaking, none of the elements you list are in $\mathbb Z[x]/<x^3+x+1>$. However, these elements do represent elements in $\mathbb Z[x]/<x^3+x+1>$. The elements you list all represent different elements in $\mathbb Z[x]/<x^3+x+1>$ but not all of them. You are missing $2$ more polynomials: $x^2+x$ and $x^2+x+1$. This will give you a complete list of representatives.

In general, given a polynomial $p(x)\in F[X]$, where $F$ is a field, the ring $R=F[x]/<p(x)>$ has cardinality $|F|^d$ where $d$ is the degree of $p(x)$. Every element in $R$ is an equivalence class of the form $q(x)+<p(x)>$, and a complete list of representatives is given by all polynomials in $F[x]$ of degree smaller than $d$.